# How to find matching rows of the first column and add quantities of the second column? Bash

Tags: python, bash, perl

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
SKU,QTY

KA006-001,2  
KA006-001,33  
KA006-001,46  
KA009-001,22  
KA009-001,7  
KA010-001,18  
KA014-001,3  
KA014-001,42  
KA015-001,1  
KA015-001,16  
KA020-001,6  
KA022-001,56
```

The first column is SKU. The second column is QTY number.

Some lines in (SKU column only) are identical.

I need to achieve the following:

```
SKU,QTY  
KA006-001,81 (2+33+46)  
KA009-001,29 (22+7)  
KA010-001,18  
KA014-001,45 (3+42)
```

so on...

I tried different things , loop statements and arrays. Got so lost, got headache.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read sku qty
do
    echo "SKU='$sku' QTY='$qty'"
    if [ "$sku" = "$sku" ]
    then
        #x=("$sku" != "$sku")
        for i in {0..3}; do echo $sku[$i]=$qty; done
    fi

done < 2asg.csv
```

Comment: add your code that you've tried

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read sku qty
do
    echo "SKU='$sku' QTY='$qty'"
 if [ "$sku" = "$sku" ]
 then
  echo "1"
  #$sku[]=$qty
 fi
  
done < 2asg.csv

Comment: as you can see, i was trying to go through some similar posts

Comment: insert code in the question

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, thanks for walking me through this. First time here and a newbie in coding.

Comment: read tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Do you need parentheses in output, I mean (2+33+46) for the first string

Comment: Have done, without parentheses, bash

Answer (score 3):

I'd use **awk**:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print} NR>1{a[$1] += $2}END{for (i in a) print i","a[i]}' file
```

If you want to ignore blank lines, you can either ignore lines less than 2 columns:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print} NR>1 && NF>1{a[$1] += $2} END{for (i in a) print i","a[i]}' file
```

or ignore ones without exactly 2 columns:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print} NR>1 && NF==2{a[$1] += $2} END{for (i in a) print i","a[i]}' file
```

Alternatively, you can check to see that the second column begins with a digit:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print} NR>1 && $2~/^[0-9]/{a[$1] += $2} END{for (i in a) print i","a[i]}' file
```

Comment: I run it, I've got a line without first column ",0". Correct the answer.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, works for me. Is it possible you've got a line in your input file that looks blank but has some non-printing character on it? Do you get the correct results if you replace `NR>1` with `$2~/[0-9]/` ?

Comment: Alright.. I suspect there may be something wonky on line 2 of your input file. You can see what it contains with greater depth by running `od -c file`, and you can `man oc` if you need some help interpreting those results. Good luck! :)

Comment: @ghoti It even sorts for me with a pipe awk -F, '$2~/[0-9]/{a[$1] += $2}END{print "SKU,QTY"; for (i in a) print i","a[i]}' 2asg.csv | sort -k1

Comment: @ghoti How do I make my code snippet look like yours with a nice grayish rectangle around it ?

Comment: uupsss...am I supposed to give the credit to @kjpires ? If so, i can't thank you more as well

Comment: @Emc2, you can format code in your comments by surrounding it with backquotes. But remember, if code is relevant to your question, click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48574132/edit) link under your question and add it there. And .. you're welcome. :) I don't get any points on this one because I didn't provide an answer, but I'm happy things are working for you and especially that you learned something!

Comment: I've modified the answer to deal with blank lines as well as get the "header" from the original file.

Answer (score 0):

For Bash 4:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A astr

while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
do
    if [ "$col1" != "SKU" ] && [ "$col1" != "" ]
    then
        (( astr[$col1] += col2 ))
    fi
done < 2asg.csv

echo "SKU,QTY"
for i in "${!astr[@]}"
do   
    echo "$i,${astr[$i]}"
done | sort -t : -k 2n
```

https://github.com/tigertv/stackoverflow-answers

Comment: Worth pointing out that associative arrays are a feature of bash 4. There are still some modern systems shipping with bash 3 (hello macOS). In macOS, bash 4 may be installed using [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: Thanks for addition